Implementing security header in index.html
I am trying to implement security header using the <meta> tag in the index.html file. I am using angular framework Here is the content:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'none';
        frame-src 'self' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com;
        script-src 'self';
        style-src 'self' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.fontawesome.com;
        font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
        img-src 'self' data: blob:;
        connect-src 'self'">

However, I cannot find any Content-Security-Policy headers in the response header section after deployment. What could be the issue?

You are not setting response headers, you are using a meta tag instead. http-equiv means you can set values that would normally be set via HTTP response headers, via this meta tag as well - but that does not "create" an actual HTTP response header; it is a different way of providing the same information.
